# Why I can't apply this theorem about differentiable functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> [MUNKRES, J.R - Analysis on Manifolds / pg.50]
>
> **Theorem 6.2** Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Suppose that the partial derivatives $D_jf_i(x)$ of the component functions of $f$
> exist at each point $x$ of $A$ and are continuous on $A$. The $f$ is
> differentiable at each point of $A$.

So, let $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$. This function is **not** differentiable at $(0,0)$ (even continuous).

However $D_1f(0,0)=D_2f(0,0)=0$. Suppose that I'm looking for the differentiability **before** look at the continuity. What's wrong if I want to use the theorem 6.2 to say that $f$ is differentiable? ( $D_1f(0,0)=D_2f(0,0)=0$, for me are like continuous functions!!)

Comment: You need to look at the functions $(x,y) \mapsto D_1f(x,y)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto D_2 f(x,y)$. If these two functions are (defined and) continuous on $A$, **then** you can conclude that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: How are you getting $D_{x}f$ exists, is continuous, and is equal to $0$? I get

$$D_x(f)(0,0)=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} {(x^2+y^2)y-2x(xy)\over (x^2+y^2)^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{y^3-x^2y\over (x^2+y^2)^2}$$

But this limit doesn't exist:  approach along $x=0$ and you get

$$\lim_{y\to 0}{1\over y}$$

Comment: $D_x(f(a))=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{f(a+xt)-f(a)}{t}$ if $a=(0,0)$ then what you have?